# Additive deserializing with Serde

Tags: rust, deserialization, serde

I'd like to *additively* deserialize multiple files over the same data structure, where "additively" means that each new file deserializes by overwriting the fields that it effectively contains, leaving unmodified the ones that it does not. The context is config files; deserialize an "app" config provided by the app, then override it with a per-"user" config file.

I use "file" hear for the sake of clarity; this could be any deserializing data source.

*Note*: After writing the below, I realized maybe the question boils down to: is there a clever use of `#[serde(default = ...)]` to provide a default from an existing data structure? I'm not sure if that's (currently) possible.

## Example

Data structure

```rust
struct S {
  x: f32,
  y: String,
}
```

"App" file (using JSON for example):

```json
{ "x": 5.0, "y": "app" }
```

"User" file overriding only "y":

```json
{ "y": "user" }
```

Expected deserializing (app, then user):

```rust
assert_eq!(s.x, 5.0);
assert_eq!(s.y, "user");
```

## Expected solution

- I'm ignoring on purpose any "dynamic" solution storing all config settings into, say, a single `HashMap`; although this works and is flexible, this is fairly inconvenient to use at runtime, and potentially slower. So I'm calling this approach out of scope for this question.
- Data structure can contain other structs. Avoid having to write too many per-struct code manually (like implementing `Deserialize` by hand). A typical config file for a moderate-sized app can contains hundreds of settings, I don't want the burden of having to maintain those.
- All fields can be expected to implement `Default`. The idea is that the first deserialized file would fallback on `Default::default()` for all missing fields, while subsequent ones would fallback on already-existing values if not explicitly overridden in the new file.
- Avoid having to change every single field of every single struct to `Option<T>` just for the sake of serializing/deserializing. This would make runtime usage very painful, where due to above property there would anyway be no `None` value ever once deserialization completed (since, if a field is missing from all files, it defaults to `Default::default()` anyway).
- I'm fine with a solution containing only a fixed number (2) of overriding files ("app" and "user" in example above).

## Current partial solution

I know how to do the first part of falling back to `Default`; this is well documented. Simply use `#[serde(default)]` on all structs.

One approach would be to simply deserialize twice with `#[serde(default)]` and override any field which is equal to its default in the app config with its value in the user config. But this 1) probably requires all fields to implement `Eq` or `PartialEq`, and 2) is potentially expensive and not very elegant (lose the info during deserialization, then try to somehow recreate it).

I have a feeling I possibly need a custom `Deserializer` to hold a reference/value of the existing data structure, which I would fallback to when a field is not found, since the default one doesn't provide any user context when deserializing. But I'm not sure how to keep track of which field is currently being deserialized.

Any hint or idea much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It sounds like your underlying goal would be solved by the [config](https://docs.rs/config/latest/config/) crate. It effectively merges all input into a single `HashMap`-like structure and only then deserializes it into a typed structure.

Comment: Alright, I feel stupid I didn't find that crate while looking into this. The question remains I think interesting, but for my practical use case yes, `config` is probably best. Thanks @kmdreko !

Comment: Its interesting, but I don't think your constraints are reasonable. You seem intent on using `serde` and doing everything in the deserialization step, but I don't think that's practical. While you probably *could* have the previous state available (probably by making a custom deserializer), its not really an intended use-case. I'd imagine having a secondary struct with `Option` fields and having a method to `apply()` them onto an existing object sounds more reasonable to me. That could likely even be done entirely by a derive macro if you want the ergonomics.

Comment: I agree with @kmdreko, the most practical way to do that would be to make a derive macro that would create a doubleganger of a struct, but with `Option`s for every field, and automatically implementing Deserialize on it, with a method to update the original structure from the `Option`y one.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, this is much appreciated! I agree the constraints are strong; this is for a hobby project, so the focus is on learning and finding an elegant solution. I'm not looking for a workaround; as I said using the `config` crate would be that. The doppelgänger certainly would work, and would be ergonomic with a derive macro, but doesn't look very elegant to me due to the duplication of data. I think @Lucretiel's mention of `deserialize_in_place` is a lot more promising. Also, `config` deserializes into a custom type repeatedly, then once into the final one, which looks neat.

Answer (score 4):

Frustratingly, `serde::Deserialize` has a method called [`deserialize_in_place`](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.136/src/serde/de/mod.rs.html#543-570) that is explicitly omitted from docs.rs and is considered "part of the public API but hidden from rustdoc to hide it from newbies". This method does exactly what you're asking for (deserialize into an existing `&mut T` object), especially if you implement it yourself to ensure that only provided keys are overridden and other keys are ignored.